# React-Router: Display homepage if not authenticated or dashboard if authenticated in at "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I have stored in redux if a user is authenticated or not. What I want to do is, once I go to `localhost:3000/` I want it to display homepage if user is not authenticated or display the dashboard if the user is authenticated. This is what I have so far.

```
export default (
 <Route path="/" component={App} >
   <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
   <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
   <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
);
```

I would like the `IndexRoute` to be conditional on authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in JSX.

```
export default (
 <Route path="/" component={App} >
    {isLoggedIn ? (
      <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    ) : (
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
    )}
</Route>
);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In the `HomePage` component you can render two other components based on authentication. For example

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  //...
  render() {
    if (currentUser) return <Dashboard /> // if user exists in the store
    else if (fetchingCurrentUser) return <LoadingView /> // if you need to fetch the user show a loading page
    else return <UnauthenticatedHomeView /> // else, return a homepage for unauthenticated users
  }
}
```

This way you can eliminate the `'/dashboard'` route altogether so the user doesn't have to travel to that route to get to their dashboard. Also, `HomePage` just acts as a container for the different possible components it can render inside of it.

Your routes would then look like this.

```
export default (
 <Route path="/" component={App} >
   <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
   <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Route>
);
```

*Another note:* you can also hook up the `onEnter` function to a route to run when the route is about to entered. Here you can do some other authenticated to protect a route. However, the example implementation above would have to change if you use `onEnter` but you now know you have that option.

Comment: Thank you for your response - really helpful.